# Why metaprogramming instead of functions?

Tags: macros, lisp, metaprogramming

I'm a JavaScript programmer who is very intrigued by Lisp after [hearing](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html) people like Eric Raymond claim that is often enlightening. Disclaimer: I'm sure there are various ways I'm being a noob and various things I'm just not understanding.

So far it seems to me like the big benefit to Lisp really comes down to the fact that it makes metaprogramming easier. So then, I'm trying to understand why metaprogramming is so useful. But as Matthew Butterick [talks about](https://practicaltypography.com/why-racket-why-lisp.html), people don't really give concrete examples of why it is useful. It's more "you're going to have to learn some Lisp and see for yourself".

I'm a little skeptical of that though. I don't see why examples can't be provided. And so, I've been searching for them. I haven't come across much, unfortunately. For the examples I have come across, I always find myself saying "Can't this just be a function?"

This `lif` [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/eowfax/comment/feg1oto/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) from Reddit is probably the best and easiest to talk about. In short, instead of doing this:

```
(let ([x (get-x)])
  (if (valid? x) 
      (use-x x) 
      (error "no x available" x)))
```

You can write a macro that allows you to do this:

```
(lif [x (get-x)]
     (valid? x)
     (use-x x) 
     (error "no x available" x))
```

Here's my question: why a macro instead of a function? To me, `lif` looks like a function that takes `get-x`, `valid?`, `use-x`, `error` and `"no x available"` as inputs and gives you whatever as the output.

Comment: The normal evaluation of a function call would evaluate all the argument expressions first and then call the function with the arguments. In LIF you don't want to evaluate all the arguments. You want to selectively evaluate them and you want them to evaluate in a binding scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why metaprogramming is useful.  It is 1958 in a variant of our universe (so, in particular, none of this happened quite like this) and I am inventing a programming language based on λ-calculus.  Functions in the paper version of this language look like

> λ *x y z*: ... something ...

But it's 1958 and parsers haven't really been invented, let alone unicode (I will pretend that lower-case has been invented).  So I invent a simple syntax, together with an in-memory data representation and a reader and printer, which I call s-expressions and use this to represent my language.  The above function is then represented as

```lisp
(lambda (x y z) ... something ...)
```

Well, I can now read this into memory and evaluate it using a program I've written in machine code which walks this data representation.  I have, in fact, invented Lisp.

Well, in the textual form of my original language function application might look like

> (λ *x y z*: ... something ...)(*thing 1* *thing 2* *thing 3*)

say, and I turn this into my s-expression representation as

```lisp
((lambda (x y z) ...) 1 2 3)
```

say.

So now I start to write the first programs in this language, and one thing I discover is that local variables are useful.  Well, I can do local variables:

```lisp
((lambda (x)
   ... x is a local variable here ...)
 1)
```

But this is hard to read, especially if there is lots of code:

```lisp
((lambda (x)
   ... 300 lines ...
   ...)
 1)
```

is just painful, because to see what the initial value of `x` is I have to look through 5 pages of printout.  I want to be able to write something that makes it easier to read my program.  I think, well, I will have to modify my evaluator function (which is in machine code) and this will be very painful, especially as I am not yet sure what the new syntax should be.

Then the light goes on: the source code of my program is a datastructure – an s-expression – and *I can write a program to take an s-expression in the nice syntax and turn it into one in the hard-to-read one*.  In particular I come up with this function:

```lisp
(lambda (form)
  (append
   (list
    (cons (quote lambda)
          (cons
           (mapcar (lambda (binding)
                     (cond
                      ((symbolp binding)
                       binding)
                      ((listp binding)
                       (car binding))))
                   (cadr form))
           (cddr form))))
   (mapcar (lambda (binding)
             (cond
              ((symbolp binding) (quote nil))
              ((listp binding) (cadr binding))))
           (cadr form))))
```

And if I name this function `let-expander` I can try it on an s-expression using a syntax which I've decided I want to use:

```lisp
> (let-expander (quote (let ((x 1) (y 2))
                         (+ x y))))
((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)
```

So now, I can write programs which have local variables written as

```lisp
(let ((x 1) ...)
  ...)
```

feed them through my `let-expander` function and then just use my old evaluator to evaluate the resulting s-expression.

*I have just invented a new language*: a language which is like my old language but has this new `let` construct in it.  It is *much* easier to read programs in this new language!  (And `let` can't be a function: its first argument is a list of variables and values, not something to be evaluated: `let` is an extension to the language, not a function defined in it.)

But wait: I don't have to stop there, do I?  Every time I decide I want a new feature in my language I can write one of these 'expander' functions and now I have that feature.   I can also use the language extended by all the previous expanders to write new ones if I'm careful.

Pretty soon I write a sort of meta-expander which knows about a table of these expanders and walks over an s-expression dutifully calling the expanders until there is nothing left to expand.  I add this as a front-end to my evaluator.

The end result of this is something completely extraordinary: I started with a primitive language which had `lambda`, `cond`, `mapcar` (which I can write in the language itself), and some primitives for dealing with and building these s-expression objects, and suddenly I have *an infinite family of languages*.  Some of these have extra general-purpose constructs, like `if` and `case` and `when` and `unless` and so on, all of which I can just implement using expanders and which become more-or-less standard.  Others have special extensions to deal with domain-specific things: the language used for the first Jupiter missions had a lot of code that looked like:

```lisp
(with-ensured-spacecraft-state (:pyros 'armed :ullage-motors 'ready)
  ...
  (fire-pyros 1 2 4)
  ...
  (ullage-motors 2.8)
  ...)
```

Constructs like this were obviously critical to the safety of the system: the code in the body of this form could not run unless the preconditions were met.  Sadly we did not anticipate the alien incursion however.

And all this came from one thing (apart from the aliens): I represented the source code of my programs in an extremely simple data structure (in particular that data structure was not full of assumptions about what things *meant*) which was available to the programs themselves.

This is why metaprogramming is useful: metaprogramming is building programming languages.

---

Notes:

- 'expanders' are macros, and 'expander functions' are macro functions in CL;
- in Common Lisp `let` is a 'special operator' – something built into the evaluator – but it does not have to be and is not in my variant world:
- same for `if`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the first part about inventing Lisp. But it's very interesting because it seems like Lisp is super simple. That makes me wonder: "Wow, how could something so simple be so powerful?" I only have a limited understanding of lambda calculus, compilers, s-expressions, readers, printers, and what is actually means to "invent a language", but, boiled down to it's essence, it sounds like Lisp is basically just `(lambda (arguments) (expressionThatIsReturned))` to define an anonymous function, and then `((lambda (x y z) ...) 1 2 3)` to apply. Is that true?

Comment: "because to see what the initial value of x is I have to look through 5 pages of printout" Just to make sure I understand: you're saying that you'd have to scroll down past the 300 lines of code and see that the anonymous function was called with an argument of `1`, right?

Comment: Wow, this was one of the more well-explained and intriguing things I can remember reading. I am very appreciative. I think I actually understood everything you've said (putting aside certain non-primary details). And I take back the question I posed in my first comment of: "Wow, how could something so simple be so powerful?" I think I can see it now, and it's truly amazing, although it'll also take some time for me to deepen that understanding.

Comment: @AdamZerner: I'm glad it helped!  I was worried it seemed like just a rambling story after I'd written it.  Yes, the '5 pages of printout' thing was about the initial value being very far from where the variable was used.  But really the underlying idea was that you can use macros to write what seem like basic language constructs, such as `let` and `if`: I just picked `let` as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Meta programming comes in many different forms.
Meta programming via macros is just one Flavor.

Meta programming with macros means extending the programming language via source code transformations. A macro takes source code and outputs new source code - either at compile time or during runtime. Macros in Lisp are designed such that they can be executed during compilation.

**Let's look at the source**

If we have an expression like this in Lisp, then what are the parts?

```
(let ((x (get-x)))
  (if (valid-p x) 
      (use-x x) 
    (error "no x available" x)))
```

`LET` is a built-in special operator with its own evaluation rules. It is not a function.

`IF` is a built-in special operator with its own evaluation rules. It is not a function.

`GET-X`, `VALID-P`, `USE-X` and `ERROR` might be functions.

`X` is a variable, introduced with a `LET` binding.

Thus neither `(LET ...)` nor `(IF ... )` are function calls.

Remember the rule to evaluate a function call in Lisp:

- evaluate all the argument expressions to their values
- find the function
- call the function with the values
- execute the function code
- return a result from the function call

The `LET` does not evaluate `((x (get-x)))` . It treats it as a binding list. `X` is a variable. `(GET-X)` is a form. `(x (get-x))` is a binding list. Evaluate the form `(GET-X)` and bind the new lexical variable `X` to the result.
The evaluate all the body expressions of the `LET` form in this lexical scope.

**a new control structure**

Now your `LIF` is also not a function, because it also uses different evaluation:

```
(lif (x (get-x))
       (valid? x)
     (use-x x) 
  (error "no x available" x))
```

`(x (get x))` does not get evaluated.

`(use-x x)` and `(error ...)` are getting evaluated based on the evaluation result of the second sub-expression `(valid-p ...)`.

Thus this can't be a function call.

Now, `LIF` is not built-in, but with a macro we can transform the `LIF` *form* into a valid Lisp form, the form we saw about with the `IF` and `LET`.
A **form** is an *expression* meant to be evaluated.

That lets you expand the *syntax* and the *semantics* of your programming language on a user/programmer level. The `LIF` macro takes code which might not be valid Lisp code and transforms it into something else, which eventually should be valid Lisp code.

Now you only need to ask yourself, what kind of transformations one can do with this. The answer actually is. that this is left to the imagination of the programmer. At first one wants to write macros which easily and simply fit into the language. But then we can also bend the rules&conventions.

An example in Common Lisp is the `LOOP` macro:

```
(LOOP FOR i FROM 0 BY 3
      REPEAT 10

      WHEN (evenp i)
       COLLECT i)

-> (0 6 12 18 24)
```

Its purpose is to a) be a sublanguage that is focused on iteration patterns and b) it should expand into efficient Lisp code (which would not be easy to be written manually and which would not be very readable). But what is strange (and controversial) about it, is that it introduces a lot of syntax into Lisp and the code does not look like the normal Lisp with a lot of parentheses. The `LOOP` form above expand into a page of lower-level code. The implementation of LOOP is complex (-> [SBCL LOOP implementation](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/loop.lisp), see how it includes even more macros implementations to implement the LOOP macro -> we can use macros in macros, too) and in effect it is a compiler written in Lisp, for an embedded language, with Lisp itself being the target language.

Thus **ONE** purpose of a macro is to implement embedded domain specific sublanguages, here a new language for iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you've seen ReactJS, you've already seen an example of what you can do with metaprogramming that you can't do with regular functions. Metaprogramming is very common in the JS community. There is a plethora of "compile-to-JavaScript" languages, and they're all examples of metaprogramming.

Metaprogramming allows you to do things that would otherwise require a new compiler.

The advantage you get from having macros built into the language is that you don't have to write an external tool to support alternative syntax like that of ReactJS. If someone was to implement ReactLisp, it would only be necessary to write some reader macros that would parse the component syntax into ordinary Lisp code.

Reader macros are functions that return Lisp code, so there's no need to write temporary files to disk.

It's so well integrated that it wouldn't even be necessary to separate ReactLisp source files from ordinary Lisp files (which you do in a React.js project by using the `.jsx` extension instead of `.js`).

In addition to reader macros, Lisp also has AST macros, which can be used to implement less radical syntax extensions. For example, years ago, someone in the JavaScript community came up with these things called "promises", and you had to call the `then` method on them to carry out the next step.

Then, because using promises was so cumbersome, they decided to add the `async` and `await` keywords to JavaScript. They're just syntactic sugar for the idioms around Promises.

You could implement promises in Lisp (but be advised that there's something called a "promise" in Scheme, and it has nothing to do with the construct that JavaScript calls a promise), and then extend the language with `async` and `await` macros which would work just as well as the `async` and `await` keywords that are built into JavaScript. Since macros are built into Lisp, there's no need for there to be a change to the language. The extension could be a library.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for those examples of JSX (that's what you mean by "alternative syntax", right?) and async/await! That really turned on a lightbulb for me. As a JavaScript programmer who mostly writes React, I definitely have a strong sense of both JSX and async/await making my life better. Similarly, I now have a sense that there are probably other things like JSX and async/await that can be dreamt up, but as you say, that'd require a compiler. It'd be cool if it didn't. I really appreciate you providing me with that insight. I now know I want to pursue Lisp further.

Answer (score 0):

So imagine you make it a function like this:

```
(define flif (bind pred consequence alternative)
  (let ([x bind])
    (if (pred x)
        (consequence x)
        (alternative x))))
```

I like to use this example instead:

```
(lif [x (get-x)]
     (< x 10)
     (if (< x 0) 0 x) 
     (- x 10))
```

In flif you need to jump thru hoops since none of the if parts are one argument functions. It looks like this:

```
(lif [x (get-x)]
     (lambda (x) (< x 10))
     (lambda (x) (if (< x 0) 0 x)) 
     (lambda (x) (- x 10)))
```

And now you're basically making this little and not very complex use so troublesome I would really rather considering using `let` and `if`:

```
(let ([x (get-x))
  (if (< x 10)
      (if (< x 0) 0 x) 
      (- x 10)))
```

Macros are syntax sugar. In Javascript we have TC39 where new features are suggested. How they do that is by implementing them in babel as a plugin. Eg. `async` / `await` was introduced this way. It's a really simple thing:

```js
async function test () {
   const x = await expression
   return x + 3;
}

// same without async / await
function test () {
   return expression.then((x) => {
     return x + 3;
   })
}
```

The idea is that the programmer can write the code more streamlined while under the hood it really did these nasty nested promise stuff. However all async functions ALWAYS return promises since the magic is limited within a async function.

I should mention that async/await adds some error handling and in the event `expression` does not become a promise it wraps the value in a promise and resolves it.

I dare you to come up with a replacement that is simpler than just using `then` without using macros/plugins. It cannot be done.

JavaScript has TC39 because it does not support macros. I belive if we made a strawman adding a way to define macros in the language, TC39 would not be needed in over 90% of the suggestions since everyone can just import a library giving you the feature to use.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding. Are `pred`, `consequence` and `alternative` the parameters of `flif`? What is `bind` doing? Why have two ifs in your example: `> 10` and then `< 0`? Wouldn't the `< 0` part never get reached because that code is only executed when it's `> 10`? Did you mean to use `flif` in the third code block?

Comment: @AdamZerner `bind`, `pred`, `consequence`, and `alternatove` are the 4 arguments of the function `lfif` yes. The first is to indicate it is the value to be cached and the 3 other wit typical names for parts of an `if` are funcitons since expressions would have been evaluated right away. To prevent  evaluation without using functions you need macros! About the nested `if` was just to show that in the macro version that is perfectly fine, while we need to wrap in lambda for a function version. I just swicthed the predicate, but it basically is the same as swithcing the last two argumenrts to fix